# Simple question about surface singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

Given $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, is it possible to find two finite familes $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ of weighted graphs, such that the weighted graph of the minimum resolution of any $\epsilon$-klt surface singularity can be written as $f\cup p \cup \dots \cup p$, where $\cup$ is the concatenation, $f\in\mathcal{F}$ and $p\in \mathcal{P}$

If I am right, this is true for some choices of $\epsilon$.

If this is true, how much do we know about the characterizations of such finite families? If not, what is the classic counter-example?